# how to send array in jquery and get in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have this code from  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp). 
 in the page lode i like to send 2 val "name" and "city"

this is the claint side the js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.post("Default.aspx",
 {
     name: "Donald Duck",
     city: "Duckburg"
 },
 function (data, status) {
     alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });

  });
```

in the server side Default.aspx.cs  i like to get the 2 val "name" and "city"

this is the serve side code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["name"];
    var status = Request.Form["city"];

    string fname = Request.Form["name"];
    string city = Request.Form["city"];


}
}
```

whay is not working???

Comment: What isn't working? Have you tried watching the request from your browser's dev tools? Have you tried debugging on the server to see what those variable values are?

Comment: you need to create a web method in your form and call that:http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Joe Enos in the debugging all val is null

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your class:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

  [WebMethod]
   public static string TestingAjax(string name,string city)
   {
    return name;
   }

}
```

and call it using jquery ajax like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var JsonData = JSON.stringify({ 
       name: "Donald Duck",
       city: "Duckburg"
});    
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/TestingAjax",
        data:  JsonData ,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad,
I copy your suggestion to my visual studio.
Its look he dont now this whay.

Here scrae copy of The problem


http://i.stack.imgur.com/xtIwr.png

Comment: try using [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] or include System.Web.Services in your file (using System.Web.Services; on top of your file)

Comment: @YehudaRaz you need to include its namespace

Comment: ok i add System.Web.Services
but now the page on lode alart error page

Comment: in the consol=
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:51782/Default.aspx/TestingAjax

Comment: Change TestingAjax(string name,string city) to something like TestingAjax(string[] testdata)